# Verify an email address is a paypal user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

I want to verify that an email address is a PayPal user. 
Is there an API call to do that?

Is there a ruby lib that does this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[GetVerifiedStatus](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getverifiedstatus-api-operation) from [PayPal's Adaptive Accounts](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-accounts) platform will do this for you.

PayPal does not have any [code samples](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-code-samples#adaptiveaccounts) or [SDKs](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#adaptiveaccounts) for Adaptive Accounts in Ruby, but I did find someone who has written the [code for GetVerifiedStatus in Ruby](http://curry.byteally.com/finding-verification-status-of-a-paypal-account-ruby-on-rails-paypal-adaptive-accounts-getverifiedstatus/).

The only change to that code you would need to have it check what type of account they have is  to change

```
if @xml['accountStatus']!=nil
    account_status = @xml['accountStatus'][0]
    #its pretty obvious from here init?
    if account_status.to_s() == "VERIFIED"
        render :text => "Account verified"
    else
        render :text => "Oopsy! Yet to be verified"
    end
else
    render :text => "Gee! sorry! something went seriously wrong"
end
```

to

```
if @xml['accountType']!=nil
    account_type = @xml['accountType'][0]
    #its pretty obvious from here init?
    if account_type.to_s() == "Business"
        render :text => "Business account!"
    elseif account_type.to_s() == "Premier"
        render :text => "Premier Account!"
    elseif account_type.to_s() == "Personal"
        render :text => "Personal account!"
    else
        render :text => "Account type not null but not a valid PayPal account type."
    end
else
    render :text => "Gee! sorry! something went seriously wrong"
end
```

**Note**: PayPal apparently has not updated their API reference page, so use the information contained on pages 65-66 in the [Adaptive Accounts guide](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptiveAccounts.pdf) for now.

Comment: That has got me a lot of the way, Thanks

Comment: @macarthy, hello! I'm using your post, but constatly get "Gee! sorry! something went seriously wrong". Can you look here - >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491352/cant-verifycheck-paypal-account ?

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [adaptiveaccounts-sdk-ruby gem](https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-ruby).  It allows you to get information about paypal accounts.

Take a look at [the sample apps](https://paypal-sdk-samples.herokuapp.com/adaptive_accounts) to see what the api can do.

Here's an example:

```
require 'paypal-sdk-adaptiveaccounts'
@api = PayPal::SDK::AdaptiveAccounts::API.new( :device_ipaddress => "127.0.0.1" )

# Build request object
@get_verified_status = @api.build_get_verified_status({
  :emailAddress => "newEmailAddress@paypal.com",
  :matchCriteria => "NONE" })

# Make API call & get response
@get_verified_status_response = @api.get_verified_status(@get_verified_status)

# Access Response
if @get_verified_status_response.success?
  @get_verified_status_response.accountStatus
  @get_verified_status_response.countryCode
  @get_verified_status_response.userInfo
else
  @get_verified_status_response.error
end
```

[here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_adaptiveaccounts.pdf) is paypal's official documentation for adaptive accounts