# Can't verify(check) paypal account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, verify

I need to verify PayPal account, when user sign_up.

I have function(source - http://curry.byteally.com/finding-verification-status-of-a-paypal-account-ruby-on-rails-paypal-adaptive-accounts-getverifiedstatus/)

I entered my credentials and changed.

I put it i my static_pages_controller(for now).

```
   def verify_paypal
     ...
//change:
if res.status == 200
 @xml = XmlSimple.xml_in(res.content)
 #check if the status node exists in the xml
if @xml['accountType']!=nil
account_type = @xml['accountType'][0]
if account_type.to_s() == "Business"
    render :text => "Business account!"
elseif account_type.to_s() == "Premier"
    render :text => "Premier Account!"
elseif account_type.to_s() == "Personal"
    render :text => "Personal account!"
else
    render :text => "Account type not null but not a valid PayPal account type."
end
   end
```

Added line in my routes.rb

```
  post "static_pages/verify_paypal"
```

In my views:

```
   <%= link_to "verify", static_pages_verify_paypal_path, :method => :post %>
```

But it constantly gives me text:

```
    "Gee! sorry! something went seriously wrong"
```

what mean, that my user isn't registered in PayPal(but it is!).

**EDTED**
From Heroku logs:

```
←[33m2012-07-15T17:22:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Started POST "/static_pages/verify_paypal" for 46.119.153.97 at 2012-07-15 17:22:56 +0000
←[33m2012-07-15T17:22:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Processing by StaticPagesController#verify_paypal as HTML
←[33m2012-07-15T17:22:56+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"xnW29ekJqp7qBNrvIZJjPSh05AMdiHWNQMvLZhevCig="}
←[36m2012-07-15T17:22:57+00:00 heroku[router]:←[0m POST sharp-cloud-3895.herokuapp.com/static_pages/verify_paypal dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=1058ms status=200 bytes=42
←[33m2012-07-15T17:22:57+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   Rendered text template (0.0ms)
←[33m2012-07-15T17:22:57+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Completed 200 OK in 1046ms (Views: 6.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.7ms)
```

First question to this line:

```
    "emailAddress" => params[:paypal]
```

Can I change it into

```
    current_user.email
```

Second question - Where is problem and what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: We'll need the actual error that gets logged to your log file when this is shown "Gee! sorry! something went seriously wrong"

Comment: The blog post you are referencing is 2 years old. It is quite possible that Paypal have changed their API and that code is no longer relevant. It also only checks against an 200 status code and nothing else, my guess would be that you are getting a 404 due to an API Change.

Comment: You are right! I need to change if statement about account type. Thanks!

Comment: I changed it, but it didn't help(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API call structure is sound.

However, when you say you entered your credentials, did you make sure that you are using the right credentials for the right environment?
Live credentials, and live accounts do not exist within the sandbox and viceversa. You can't check a live account's status against the checkbox because it simply does not exists in the sandbox "universe".

That would be the first thing to look at. If you feel your environments are correct, can you post the contents of `res.content` to see what came back from the HTTP call?

Comment: Way beyond the scope of this question. This explains how to write to the Heroku Log

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't see command for loggin result what came back from PayPal. I can show you my log or this should be included manually ?

Comment: I'm sending authencity token somehow. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [adaptiveaccounts-sdk-ruby gem](https://github.com/paypal/adaptiveaccounts-sdk-ruby)