# Do I need PayPal Preapproval for automatic payments TO USERS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

In my application I will have function, which will pay TO my users every month.

What kind of preapproval I should have ? Is this neccessary thing ?

Can you recommend me any good gem for this ?

Comment: I removed my answer since you're paying YOUR users, not getting money from them. if you're paying your users, that's a different ballgame altogether (and is likely very difficult because you're sending cash to them, not taking from them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PreApprovals are for collecting money (i.e. they pay you). For sending money, you need to look at adaptive payments, in particular the Implicit Payment feature.

It allows you to programmatically send money out of your own account (i.e. You pay them).

PayPal currently doesn't have any product that automates this, so you need to write a script on your side that will make that API call once a month for all your users.

Check out page 25 for more info. [ https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_AdaptivePayments.pdf ]

As far as a Gem goes, i don't believe there is one explicitly for this, however you could probably tweak ActiveMerchant (Or at least use it as a starting point) for this purpose, as it's basically a **Pay** API call, with the exception that you specify yourself as sender.

Comment: Thanks)You have already answered me at some qustion.Very simmilar. Can you look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11491352/cant-verifycheck-paypal-account ?

Comment: and what gem you can reccomend me ?

Comment: As I mentioned, go look at ActiveMerchant. It's a pretty popular eCommerce framework for ROR.

Here's a branch that someone made for adaptive payments. (HAven't used it, this is just some basic googling...)

https://github.com/jpablobr/active_paypal_adaptive_payment